# Getting little play controls over my flash video?

Tags: html, flash, video, web, embed

I have an .swf that plays a small flash video on a website, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get little controls similar to this virtual spokesperson on this website.

http://washerwizards.com/

I'm not flash savvy, but I keep reading about skin files etc. I'm unsure of how to make them work though.

Comment: Skinning the player would be one way to go, but it isn't particularly easy. You could also create your own buttons though and control the video through code.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, I literally just now started doing just that. I created some PNG buttons in photoshop, and have added the buttons inside my swf. My play button works, but I'm still fiddling with the pause and trying to get the play button to start where it paused. Learning so much!